# New iOS Production Push Certificate is not working

Tags: ios, iis-7, certificate, apple-push-notifications

I have lost all my certificates to send Push notifications (someone robbed our office), so I have created new ones in the Apple portal.

My Dev Push certificate is working like a charm, but when I upload the Web App to the server and tried to use the Prod Push certificate, everything seems to work but I never get the Push.

I know for sure that the server is not the one that is having the problem because the certificates of other App are working, with the same code of my Web Page.

This is not the first time I tried to send Push Notifications, in fact everything was working with the old certificates.

This are the things that I have done so far:

- I have installed the .cer and the .p12 in the server.
- I have set my code to be executed for production (push.apple.com not
  sandbox.push.apple.com).
- My App always refresh the Push Id in the server (I have different Push ID's).
- I'm using the App from TestFlight  to test the production enviroment
  (as I said before in Dev all works).

I have done this hundred of times but I don't understand why is not working now.

Right now I have all the certificates active in the Apple Portal, Do I have to revoke the old ones?.

Does anyone have any thought?.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

**UPDATE 1:**

I have tested the Pro certificate in an exe app and works frome everywhere I use it and I have tested it too from my Visual Studio, changing the Push Id manually in the DB and I have received the Push, but if I use it from the IIS the push gets lost, but in the same server and in the same code with an old Push from another App everything is working and I have my push.

So, so far:

- Same code in the Pro Web Server Old push certificate from other App works.
- Test exe program works everywhere.
- Web code from Visual Studio works with all certificates.
- Same code in the Pro Web Server New push certificate is not working.

**UPDATE 2**

The only difference that I have found is that the app that it is working is in the 80 port and the new is in the 8080 so I have have configured the Firewall to allow any outbound connections on that port and is not working.

**UPDATE 3**

I have added the application to the same Website and the same port and still not working.

Comment: Did you find out what was the solution? Have you revoke the old cert?

Comment: @Prcela sorry but there is not good answer to this one, check my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a good answer to this question, the problem in my case was that someone changed the Web.config of the Web Application that sends the Push, so there was a library missing in the configurations.

It took me a while to find it and to find the guilty one.

May be good to remove this question but I don't know how.

Regards and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Port 2195 is responsible to send notification to APNS server. Make sure you send notification via. 2195

Comment: Ok!! Thanks let me ckeck, i will keep you posted

Answer (score 0):

Could you have it linked to the wrong app profile?